# Salesforce-Phonegap and Sencha touch integration issue

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I have developing an iOS app using Salesforce mobile SDK 1.4 with Sencha Touch for the front end. I am using Phonegap/Cordova version 2.2. My application is able to logon successfully with Salesforce. I can load app.js on the simulator smoothly but on a real device I am getting a WHITE BLANK SCREEN.

I am not getting any error at logs/console. I am using sencha touch version 2.1

This is my app.js

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Sencha',
controllers: ['Main'],
views: ['Main'],
stores: ['Contacts'],
models: ['Contact'],

launch: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'mainpanel'
    });
},                
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest stripping out ext.js and trying to do basic js output then slowing adding layers until you find the one that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue several times on my hybrid apps specifically on devices. In addition to what Kevin mentioned, I would recommend that A) You upgrade to the latest Sencha Touch version (2.3) - the post dates back to January and I believe 2.1 was indeed the latest version at that time B) You may want to cross-verify the results by using the official Sencha Touch connector for Salesforce REST API (this was unveiled in July 2013 at SenchaCon). C) If you are using multiple JS libraries (other than Sencha Touch), comment those out one by one to see if that makes a difference.